# \listofalgorithms not working with algorithm2e in document class puthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

I am using the algorithm2e package to add some algorithms to my thesis with the following line in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
```

However, I am unable to add the list of algorithms to my table of contents. I get the following error message when I try to use \listofalgorithms

```
(./doc.loa
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \edef 
l.2 ...gnorespaces Simple Algorithm}}{1}{algocf.1}
```

I believe the issue is related to the use of these two files -- [`puthesis.cls`](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/supported/puthesis.cls) and [`pulongtable.sty`](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/supported/pulongtable.sty) which I am required to use for my thesis. I have included a minimum working example below which throws the error when I run pdflatex on it twice.

*Added by muzimuzi Z*: To run the following example, you need to aquire [`notoccite.sty`](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/supported/notoccite.sty) as well.

```
\documentclass[ece,bypass]{puthesis}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\title{MWE}
\author{Zuko Aang}{Aang, Zuko}
\campus{Indianapolis}

\begin{document}
\volume

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Hello}
\section{Test}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Simple Algorithm}
  Hello
  \label{alg:Simple Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Would you please provide an [mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that others can use it as a start to help you?

Comment: Hi, I have added an mwe and more details as suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Redefine `\l@algocf`:

```
\documentclass[ece,bypass]{puthesis}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{MWE}
\author{Zuko Aang}{Aang, Zuko}
\campus{Indianapolis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@algocf{\@dottedtocline{1}{\smalltocskip}{1em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\volume
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Hello}
\section{Test}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Simple Algorithm}
  Hello
  \label{alg:Simple Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

#### Explanation

In `puthesis.cls`, command `\@dottedtocline` is redefined to accept an extra argument as its new second argument. This `#2` represents the extra vertical skip before every content item (e.g., a section in `\tableofcontents` or an algorithm `\listofalgorithms`). In `puthesis.cls`, `\smalltocskip` is passed to the `#2` of `\@dottedtocline` in redefinition of commands like `\l@section` and `\l@subsection`. For example,

```
% before, in report.cls
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}

% after, in puthesis.cls (comments are copied from puthesis.cls too)
% Got these lines using "grep dotted report.cls" and changed
% as needed for new \@dottedtocline \vskip parameter.
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{\smalltocskip}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{\smalltocskip}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
```

Hence, the solution is to redefine the internal command of an algorithm item in `\listofalgorithms`, which is `\l@algocf`, to sync with the change of `\@dottedtocline`.

```
% before, in algorithm2e.sty
% \newcommand*\l@algocf{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{2.3em}}

% after, in my answer
\renewcommand*\l@algocf{\@dottedtocline{1}{\smalltocskip}{1em}{2.3em}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the trick. I am very grateful. Btw, I did include links to puthesis.cls and pulongtable.sty as hyperlinks in the edited question. Is that not the correct way to include links?

Comment: @zuko I missed the links in your question. So sorry. Updated my answer.